# Autodesk Forge - Post Jobs - Must files be in buckets and proper URN

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am working on doing a [post job](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/) and I am confused about where files need to be to run the job and the proper urn.

The examples all use a file that the user uploads to a bucket. I am trying to run the post job on a file that a user has created in Fusion 360 and that he has selected through a GUI I created. The urn in question is obtained by letting the user select the hub, project, folder(s), and file. I then use this file urn on the post job.

I keep getting back the response of :

```
Failed to download the design description for the input design.
```

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to do this from a users hub or do all items have to be in buckets?
2. Where are those translated files stored once created? If I want to get data like volume and mass without storing the translated file, is that possible?

I took the "urn:" off the front of the urn and got a different error, which I believe meant that it couldn't find any file.

```
Invalid 'design' parameter.
```

So, it looks like the urn I am using is finding a file but there is an issue somewhere that is preventing that file from being accessed or translated or something.

Answer (score 0):

> I keep getting back the response of : Failed to download the design description for the input design.

For Fusion 360 files make sure the extension name of the object is f2d/f3d. BTW Forge Viewer support these two formats directly so you don't have to translate to SVF for Viewer to visualize them.

> Is it possible to do this from a users hub or do all items have to be in buckets?

For hub project items use the Data Management API to obtain the object ID - be sure to include the version parameter in your URN - see [GET projects/:project_id/folders/:folder_id/contents](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-contents-GET/) and use the `id` of the item as your URN as well as tutorial [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/download-file/#step-3-find-the-resource-item-in-a-project-folder) to help you understand how project folder items work.

> Where are those translated files stored once created? If I want to get data like volume and mass without storing the translated file, is that possible?

The translated derivatives would be stored separately and you can access them through the derivative [manifest](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-GET/). Use [GET :urn/metadata/:guid/properties](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/) to query derivative properties but you will need to translate the model (to any format will do) in order to extract properties - see tutorial [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/extract-geometry-from-source-file/).